# What is the best way to give an injured bird water?

Tags: birds, bird-feeding

There is this pigeon that I found the other day, it couldn't fly, had a chewing-gum attached to its wing, and probably a hurt neck, it would just sit and weep.

I fed the bird with water using a cotton ball. I dipped the cotton ball in water and press it gently near its beak to feed water, and the bird did actually drink the water.

I thought using a dropper tube would be a better choice?
What would you do?

Info: I took the bird to a vet doctor and its absolutely fine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are several ways to give birds a drink.

1. if it is calm just dip the beak in water and let it drink naturally. Your method of dropping water of cotton wool is fine.
2. Dropper, syringe or drop-wise from a teaspoon is fine. Just a drop or two at a time. Don't force water into the bird, just allow a drop at a time to fall into the beak, let it swallow.

It probably only needs a few drops at a time, a pigeon will probably only need 50 to 80ml a day

If it is a racing pigeon it probably needs several days rest and some wholegrain / split maize.